# Breakpoints in TSQL

Tags: sql, database, debugging

I have long stored procedure to debug. How can I set breakpoints in my MS Menagement Studio?

This is for MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tutorials/articles which might help you:

- [SQL Server 2008: The Debugger is back](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/07/31/sql-server-2008-the-debugger-is-back/)
- [Debugging Stored Procedures in SQL Server 2005](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article27.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008 TSQL Debugger is back in SSMS](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1695/sql-server-2008-tsql-debugger-is-back-in-ssms/)
- [Debugging SQL Server CLR functions, triggers and stored procedures](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1624/debugging-sql-server-clr-functions-triggers-and-stored-procedures/)